# Python 3 FancyURLopener cookie handling

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.x, urllib

A website that I am trying to retrieve a file from requires a cookie and I can't seem to figure out how to add cookie handling while using FancyURLopener.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
user_agents = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
    'Opera/9.25 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en)',
]
site_file = "somesite.com/pic.jpeg"
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener, object):
    version = choice(user_agents)
myopener = MyOpener()
myopener.retrieve(site_file, "pic.jpeg")
```

I also tried using something like this, but was unsure how to actually retrieve the file with this method.

```
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
request = urllib.request.Request(site)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
request.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0')
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the file using:

```
import shutil
from contextlib import closing

with closing(opener.open(request)) as src, open(filename, "wb") as dest:
    shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest)
```